# Magento 2 : Add child products return error using REST API

Tags: magento2, product, upgrade, rest-api, version

`Magento 2.1.8.`

I firstly successfully use rest `API` to create a parent item (configurable item). Then I use the `API` to create a `child item` (simple product item) under the `parent item`. The `Magento 2` backend gives me `"Products "%1"` and `"%2"` have the same set of attribute values." error.

See following logs:

```
1. successfully create a parent item:

ACTION:

PUT

URL:

/index.php/rest/V1/products/8100

HEADER:

Content-Type:application/json

Accept:application/xml

............


RESPONSE:

HTTPCODE:

200

RESPONSE:

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<response>

  <id>361</id>

  <sku>8100</sku>

...........


Then I try to add a child item:

ACTION:

POST

URL:

/rest/V1/configurable-products/8100/child

HEADER:

Content-Type:application/json

Accept:application/xml

REQUEST:

{"childSku": "8116"}



RESPONSE (with error):

HTTPCODE:

400

RESPONSE:

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<response>

  <message>Products "%1" and "%2" have the same set of attribute values.

</message>

  <parameters>

    <item>372</item>

    <item>337</item>

  </parameters>

</response>
```

It used to work on `2.0.11`, I upgraded to `2.1.8` then lots of my `API` calls are not working. This is just too hard to `integrate` other `software` to `Magento 2`.

Comment: Did you find an issue were you able to fix can you share?

Comment: I am also wondering if you have sorted out what the problem was?